# Minimum distance between 2 values in a list, considering list is connected between end and start

Tags: python, list, cycle

I want to find the minimum distance between any 2 values in a list. However, I need the minimum distance considering both 'clockwise' and 'anticlockwise' movement.

For example, I have the list [0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1]. Say I want the distance between the pair (4,1)

Moving 'clockwise' the result is obviously 4 considering the difference in index. However, If one moves 'anti-clockwise' and considers the list connected, so 0 is a neighbour to 1. The distance would be 2, which is the result I want.

How can I achieve this?

I thought about joining the lists.

[0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1]

However, then there are duplicates and I'm not sure how one would choose between these.

Comment: Is the list unique to begin with?

Comment: why not just calculate both? The "reverse" direction distance is the index of 4 + length(list) - index of 1

Comment: `How can I achieve this?` - Seems you have defined what you want to accomplish. Start by writing down in words discrete things you might need to do to accomplish it; then sit back, look at those things, and organize them in a logical sequence; attempt to translate each discrete step into code, sometimes it helps to make functions; run your first attempt step by step - either with pencil and paper pretending you are the interpreter or with a debugger (if you are not using an ide you should get one); assess your attempt; adjust; repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One way is to note how you get reversed index to begin with. Pretend that `index(1) == -1`. The distance is now `index(4) - index(1) = 1 + 1 = 2`. `-1` just means `len(a) - 1` in this case. So for every pair of indices `i1` and `i2`, you compute the two quantities `max(i1, i2) - min(i1, i2)`, and `min(i1, i2) + len(a) - max(i1, i2)`, and take the smaller one.

If the values in the list are not unique, you will need to find all occurrences for each one, and use something like `itertools.product` to find the minimum distance.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you. I implemented it and it's working perfectly.